Possible to undo a commit in Visual Studio?
I am using VS 2022.
I create a new branch and do some work on it.
Click Commit All and realised i have included some things i dont want to push to the repository.
Is there a way to undo this commit so i can have all the changed files displaying in the Git Changes tab as if i had not committed the changes?
I opened up Git > Manage Branches and see the commit i did and see a couple of options.
I have read a few articles but they seem to be confusing with using commands whereas in VS im used to the GUI and although i see a lot of options to undo i dont really know which is the appropriate one for this case i.e.
revert, Reset and keep changes, Reset and delete changes.
I saw this article In Visual Studio 2015 how to reverse/undo a commit in Git? but i need to be sure this option (Reset and keep changes) would do undo and show the files as if i had not done a commit?

VS will behind the scenes just invoke the git commands for you. My advice is therefore to learn to deal with the CLI yourself. You can just open up a command prompt anywhere within your repository and execute that command and it'll work. The VS UI will also update appropriately. You can even use the Developer PowerShell included with VS which may be the most straighforward way. For the commands there are plenty of threads here on SO.

So which command are you suggesting that would resolve this?

Please check How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?.

For this i used git reset --soft HEAD~1 which did the trick but would be nice to know the equivalent GUI option

@TTT apologies. Retracted!

You were just about there:

I opened up Git > Manage Branches and see the commit i did and see a couple of options.

You'll want to learn more about the different git reset options and how they work, but the two reset options that Visual Studio offers are --mixed and --hard. To use the reset option, in the branch history graph, select the  commit that you wish to reset your branch pointer to, and this will remove all of the commits above it (and if a merge commit is being removed it will also remove all commits brought in by that merge).
For your use case where you have one commit that you wish to remove, and re-commit some of it, select the parent commit of that commit (the one below your commit in the graph), right click on it, and select "Reset->Keep Changes (--mixed)". This will put you back into the state you were in before you created the commit, with nothing staged yet.
Side Notes:

If you don't want to keep any of your changes, you should choose --hard.
Note that VS doesn't offer the option to do a --soft reset in the GUI, but the only difference with --soft is that all your changes would be staged already, which you can manually do in the GUI after reset with --mixed.
The GUI command is identical to running the following command from the command line, e.g. a mixed reset: git reset --mixed <selected-commit-id>


You can effect an undo from within VS, but it's not an actual undo, it's a compensating commit that reverts you back to the prior state of the offending commit.
From the Search dropdown in the main menu select Feature Search. Type in View History or View Branch History and select that. A history of your commits will be listed. Right click the commit you want to undo and choose Revert.
I'd show a screenshot but I'd have to redact everything.

OP wants reset, not revert: "Is there a way to undo this commit so i can have all the changed files displaying in the Git Changes tab as if i had not committed the changes?"
